# Send Evil Troy back to the hell that he came from! Oh, wait it's gone already?

Tags: zombicide-black-plague

Sorry for the click bait title, but I have a rules query about Evil Troy as a necromancer. His card states:

> When killed, put him back in **his** Spawn Zone and don't remove a Spawn Token, unless a Damage 3 (or more) Attack or Dragon Fire was used.

Emphasis is mine.

From the rule book, when you kill a necromancer, you can:

> Killing a Necromancer slows the invasion . If you manage to kill it, choose a Spawn Zone (including its own Necromancer Spawn Zone) and remove it from the board . If the Necromancer Spawn token is still on the board after this removal, replace it with a standard one.

Suppose I have killed a necromancer other than Evil Troy and I decide to remove Evil Troy's spawn zone. **What happens if I kill Evil Troy after his spawn zone is removed? What happens if I used a weapon with a damage of less than 3?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of the rules is this:
When you select a Spawn Zone to remove you have 2 choices:

- A regular Spawn Zone (not a Necromancer Spawn Zone)
- The Necromancer Spawn Zone for the defeated Necromancer

In the first case the Necromancer Spawn Zone for the defeated Necromancer becomes a regular Spawn Zone.

This means you cannot choose the Necromancer Spawn Zone for any other Necromancer currently in play. Thus, when Evil Troy is killed, his Necromancer Spawn Zone should still be on the board.